# Errors with generic class extending other generic class

Tags: java, generics

I've got a problem with generic classes and I'm going to explain it with my example classes:

BinaryTree

```
public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
```

Indexed

```
public abstract class Indexed<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Indexed<T>> {
```

IndexedBinaryTree

```
public class IndexedBinaryTree<T extends Indexed<? extends Comparable<Indexed<?>>>> extends BinaryTree<T> {
```

Example class which extends Indexed

```
public class Vokabel extends Indexed<String> {
```

The IndexedBinaryTree isn't working. What I'm trying to do is having an BinaryTree which contains Indexed objects and can be created like this:

```
IndexedBinaryTree<Vokabel> ibt = new IndexedBinaryTree<>();
```

The **Error** NetBeans is giving me:

> type argument ? extends Comparable> is not within bounds of
>   type-variable T
>         where T is a type-variable:
>           T extends Comparable declared in class Indexed
>
> ```
> > expected
>
> type argument T#1 is not within bounds of type-variable T#2
>   where T#1, T#2 are type-variables:
>     T#1 extends Indexed<? extends Comparable<Indexed<?>>> declared in class IndexedBinaryTree
>     T#2 extends Comparable<T#2> declared in class BinaryTree
> ```

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"? Details, please.

Comment: Define doesn't work. Post the error and what the expected behaviour is.

Comment: Edited main post (http://i.imgur.com/SRx0iDv.png - Screenshot of the error)

Comment: I don't understand this declaration: `Indexed<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Indexed<T>>`. What's the purpose of forcing `T` to be `Comparable` then impelementing `Comparable` on something different?

Comment: You may need something like `K extends Comparable<K>, T extends Indexed<K>`. You are getting confused by my comment above. You seem to want `T` to be `Indexed` _and to be_ the type argument to `Indexed`.

Comment: That would mean that I have to specify 2 classes when I initialize a new IndexedBinaryTree.. So IndexedBinaryTree<Vokabel> wouldn't work anymore because I would have to do IndexedBinaryTree<String, Vokabel> although Vokabel already knows that it's index is a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compiles:

```
class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {}
abstract class Indexed<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Comparable<Indexed<T>> {}
class IndexedBinaryTree<T extends Indexed<?>> extends BinaryTree<T> {}
```